# What string of characters should a source send to disambiguate the byte-encoding they are using?

Tags: unicode, encoding, decoding

I'm decoding bytestreams into unicode characters without knowing the encoding that's been used by each of a hundred or so senders.

Many of the senders are not technically astute, and will not be able to tell me what encoding they are using. It will be determined by the happenstance of the toolchains they are using to generate the data.

The senders are, for the moment, all UK/English based, using a variety of operating systems.

Can I ask all the senders to send me a particular string of characters that will unambiguously demonstrate what encoding each sender is using?

I understand that there are libraries that use heuristics to guess at the encoding - I'm going to chase that up too, as a runtime fallback, but first I'd like to try and determine what encodings are being used, if I can.

(Don't think it's relevant, but I'm working in Python)

Comment: What “sending” is this about? Email bodies? Email attachment? Web form submissions? Carrier pigeon deliveries?

Comment: I think the question is interesting: is there a limited set of characters sufficient to guess character encoding?  Schemes like the Firefox library are forced to deal with unpredictable streams.

Comment: @Jukka Hey. I want to be helpful if I can, but I don't yet understand why it matters. They are streams of bytes, what does it matter where they came from? As it happens, my streams of bytes, when my code receives them, are files on disk, which were created by a Django process of ours which received them from my 'senders' in a web request.

Comment: @Jonathan, it matters because people should be expected to make mistakes when asked to include characters. So it’s a different issue if your special string can be *automatically* inserted into the data that someone is sending. And if computer programs are involved, they can perform wrong conversions and mess things up. This looks more complicated than the test string issue; to distinguish between encodings commonly used in UK/English environment, I would expect a string like “éš–α” do the job.

Comment: @Jukka Thanks, I see what you mean now. Yes, now that you explain, I agree that it seems hard to ensure that my senders are all genuinely entering the correct specified characters. They are all using completely different tools to produce the textual data. Some exporting from Excel or similar, some using exports from enterprisey software, some homegrown tools.

Comment: @Jukka, Also, I am of course curious about how you ended up with the string "éš–α". Did you choose those characters specially? Did you carefully consider the number of characters that would be required? Or is this a seat-of-the-pants hunch based on your experience? Many thanks.

Comment: @Jonathan, I just picked up some characters that have different codes in encodings that might be applied, and would thus distinguish e.g. UTF-8, UTF-16, ISO-8859-1, windows-1252, Mac Roman, common DOS code pages, etc., from each other. A major problem would be: can we know what happens to characters that are not representable in the encoding at all?

Comment: @Jukka, An excellent question. In the general case, assuming widely diverse toolchains of the senders, and general lack of technical expertise (my senders are not primarily technology-oriented organisations), I guess the answer is no. I'll percolate more on this...

Comment: It was already asked here, but I will ask again: what do we know about the text that is encoded? And, what is the encoding variety? Who sends non-UTF8 text, and why? In what language is the text?

Comment: @Pavel Hey. Generally the text that is encoded is mostly english - although it contains some foreign names and words. The data is in delimiter-separated format or json. I'm in close contact with the senders during integration, and think I'll be able to ask them to send any specific data I choose. The encoding depends on the tools used to generate the data, which varies widely - some off the shelf, some hand-coded. Many Windows programs, as I understand it, send non-utf8 text, such as cp1252 (aka Windows-1252) or the very similar latin-1. We have thus far seen a single example of utf32le.

Comment: UTF-8 is so popular today.. including on Windows.. maybe you can define it as requirement?

Comment: Unfortunately not, most of the organisations we work with have large existing systems which we have to integrate with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A full answer to this question depends on a lot of factors, such as the range of encodings used by the various upstream systems, and how well your users will comply with instructions to type magic character sequences into text fields, and how skilled they will be at the obscure keyboard combinations to type the magic character sequences.

There are some very easy character sequences which only some users will be able to type. Only users with a Cyrillic keyboard and encoding will find it easy to type "Ильи́ч" (Ilyich), and so you only have to distinguish between the Cyrillic-capable encodings like UTF-8, UTF-16, iso8859_5, and koi8_r. Similarly, you could come up with Japanese, Chinese, and Korean character sequences which distinguish between users of Japanese, simplified Chinese, traditional Chinese, and Korean systems.

But let's concentrate on users of western European computer systems, and the common encodings like ISO-8859-15, Mac_Roman, UTF-8, UTF-16LE, and UTF-16BE. A very simple test is to have users enter the Euro character '€', U+20AC, and see what byte sequence gets generated:

- byte ['\xa4'] means iso-8859-15 encoding
- bytes ['\xe2', '\x82', '\xac'] mean utf-8 encoding
- bytes ['\x00', '\xac'] mean utf-16be encoding
- bytes ['\xac', '\x00'] mean utf-16le encoding
- byte ['\x80'] means cp1252 ("Windows ANSI") encoding
- byte ['\xdb'] means macroman encoding
- iso-8859-1 won't be able to represent the Euro character at all. iso-8859-15 is the Euro-supporting successor to iso-8859-1.
- U.S. users probably won't know how to type a Euro character. (OK, that's too snarky. 3% of them will know.)

You should check what each of these byte sequences, interpreted as any of the possible encodings, is not a character sequence that users would likely type themselves.  For instance, the '\xa4' of the iso-8859-15 Euro symbol could also be the iso-8859-1 or cp1252 or UTF-16le encoding of '¤', the macroman encoding of '§', or the first byte of any of thousands of UTF-16 characters, such as U+A4xx Yi Syllables, or U+01A4 LATIN SMALL LETTER OI. It would not be a valid first byte of a UTF-8 sequence. If some of your users submit text in Yi, you might have a problem.

The [Python 3.x documentation, *7.2.3. Standard Encodings*](http://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) lists the character encodings which the Python standard library can easily handle. The following program lets you see how a test character sequence is encoded into bytes by various encodings:

```
>>> for e in ['iso-8859-1','iso-8859-15', 'utf-8', 'utf-16be', 'utf-16le', \
... 'cp1252', 'macroman']:
...     print e, list( euro.encode(e, 'backslashreplace'))
```

So, as an expedient, satisficing hack, consider telling your users to type a '€' as the first character of a text field, if there are any problems with encoding. Then your system should interpret any of the above byte sequences as an encoding clue, and discard them. If users want to start their text content with a Euro character, they start the field with '€€'; the first gets swallowed, the second remains part of the text.

Comment: A well-reasoned and thoughtful response. Thank-you.